# Why is $\int_{0}^{\infty} 0\, dx = 0$ and not indeterminate?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

It might seem that

\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} 0\, dx &= 0\int_{0}^{\infty} dx\\
&= 0\cdot x\,\bigg\rvert_0^\infty\\
&= 0\cdot \infty
\end{align}

which is indeterminate. Right?

Comment: Your mistake is in the very first step. It would be an instance of a theorem but the hypotheses are not satisfied. Please look at the theorem carefully, especially what are the assumed hypotheses.

Comment: I know. I just put this up there as a model of the naive approach. :) (Notice that I answered my own question.)

Comment: There is no such thing as "indeterminate". An expression involving limits either exists or not and, if it exists, it is either included in some set of privileged numbers or not. Talking of "indeterminate forms" is just a way to remind a particular class of superior primates of instances where a certain method does not work. In grown-up terms, one may very well name them "procedural flaws due to sloppiness".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite. We are taking two limits--the integral, which itself is a limit, and the limits of definite integration. The order of these limits is important; in general, these limits do not commute. The fundamental theorem of calculus (or second fundamental theorem, depending on the textbook) says that

\begin{equation}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx = F(b) - F(a)\end{equation}

where $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$ evaluated at $a$ and $b$, respectively (with the usual assumptions of integrability, existence of $f(x)$ on the interval $(a,b)$, etc.). Furthermore,

\begin{align}\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx &= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx\\
&= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[F(b) - F(a)\right]
\end{align}

This limit has to be taken *after* we integrate. Therefore:

\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} 0\, dt &=
\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{b} 0\, dx\\
&= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[0 \int_{0}^{b} \, dx\right]\\
&= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}[0\cdot b - 0\cdot 0]\\
&= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} 0\\
&= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: The moral of the story is you can't pretend $\infty$ is a number.

Comment: How did you realise your mistake so quickly ? This answer seems as old as the question.

Comment: @A---B It was answered at exactly the same time as asking the question. I believe OP used the "answer your own question" option which comes up when you ask a question.

Comment: @JohnDoe Correct. I didn't see a similar question posted before and figured that someone's going to look this up at some point.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks. I have never seen anybody use that feature, so it didn't strike me at all.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

With Riemann integration, the (improper) integral is defined as the
limit of $\int_0^L \cdots $ as $L \to \infty$ which will result in zero in this case.

With Lebesgue integration, we work in the extended reals and define $0 \cdot \infty = 0$. Then the integral is taken as the $\sup$ of
the integrals of simple, non negative functions majorised by the function $x \mapsto 0$. In this case, the function itself is the only suitable simple function and in that case we define
$\int 0 dx = 0 \cdot m[0,\infty) = 0$.